# Metrics list of a web service monitored using JMX

Tags: web, service, monitoring, jmx, metrics

I am planning to monitor a web service by using JMX and I would like to know the list of metrics that can be collected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best here is to connect to your running JVM with e.g. `jconsole` and then there switch to the MBean tab and have a look at the available MBeans with their attributes.

There will probably be much more values than what you want to collect though, so you need to select. Good candidates are memory and garbage collection statistics and also values regarding the servlet container or similar.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I am looking at for the moment.